# Find the solution to the Integral Equation:

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the solution to the Integral Equation:
>
> $\phi(x)=x+\int _0^x \sin (x-t)\phi(t) dt $

The solution is given as $x+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}$.

**My try**:

$K(x,t)=\sin (x-t)=K_1(x,t)$;

$K_n(x,t)=\int _t^x K(x,z) K_{n-1}( z,t) dz$;

I got $K_2(x,t)=\sin(-x-t)-\sin (x-3t)-(x-t)\cos (x-t)$.

So it's getting difficult.I am appearing for an exam where the time given will be small for this 1 mark question.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiate to get
$\phi'(x) = 1+ \int_0^x \cos(x-t) \phi(t) dt$ and once more to get
$\phi''(x) = \phi(x) - \int_0^x \sin(x-t) \phi(t) dt$. Hence the equation is
$0= x  - \phi''(x)$.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Thanks again!

Comment: I think it's fine now Joe.  (+1)

Comment: @Dr.MV: Thanks! I am having an error prone morning while procrastinating.

Comment: I've had many error-prone mo"nem"ts.

Comment: @Dr.MV: :-) ${}{}{}$

Comment: The formula lets you compute $\phi(x)$.

Comment: Yes thank you got it :-)

Comment: @Dr.MV: Btw, your kindness cheered me up at a much needed moment on a bad MSE day :-). Thanks.

Comment: @copper.hat Joe, I'm sorry to hear about your bad MSE day, but please to hear that I was able to cheer you.  I've had a few bad MSE days too.  There are some on this site who are sarcastic, discourteous, rude, arrogant, and down right mean.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the solution over $[0, \infty)$ of

$$\phi(x)=x+\phi(x)*\sin(x)$$

Take the Fourier/Laplace transform and solve.

Comment: How did you arrive at that equation?

Comment: @S.C.B. The integral $\int_a^x f(x-t) g(t)dt$ is the definition of the convolution. So, whenever when you see an integral of this form, you can replace it by the convolution... I just recognized the DEFINITION of convolution in the integral.

Answer (score 2):

Take **Laplace** of this Integral Equation:
$${\cal L}(\phi)={\cal L}(x)+{\cal L}(\sin x){\cal L}(\phi) $$
$${\cal L}(\phi)=\frac{\frac{1}{s^2}}{1-\frac{1}{s^2+1}}=\frac{s^2+1}{s^4}=\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{1}{s^4}$$
so
$$\phi(x)=x+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}$$